# sinon - spy on toString method

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, spy

In my file, I have something like this:

```
if(somevar.toString().length == 2) ....
```

How can I spy on `toString` from my test file? I know how to spy on things like parseInt with:

```
let spy = sinon.spy(global, 'parseInt')
```

But that doesn't work with `toString` since it's called on the value, I tried spying on `Object` and `Object.prototype`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Spying on Object.prototype will only work if toString() method was called on an instance of an object, same for arrays (using Array.prototype instead of Object.prototype).

Comment: I tested spying on String.prototype, and I can check that toString has been called indeed, but how can I check the parameters it was called on? calledWith doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `sinon.spy` or `sinon.stub` on a method of primitive value like:

`sinon.spy(1, 'toString')`. This is wrong.

You should call them on the `Class.prototype` of primitive value. Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export function main(somevar: number) {
  if (somevar.toString(2).length == 2) {
    console.log("haha");
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main } from "./";
import sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("49866123", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("should log 'haha'", () => {
    const a = 1;
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, "log");
    const toStringSpy = sinon.stub(Number.prototype, "toString").returns("aa");
    main(a);
    expect(toStringSpy.calledWith(2)).to.be.true;
    expect(logSpy.calledWith("haha")).to.be.true;
  });
  it("should do nothing", () => {
    const a = 1;
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, "log");
    const toStringSpy = sinon.stub(Number.prototype, "toString").returns("a");
    main(a);
    expect(toStringSpy.calledWith(2)).to.be.true;
    expect(logSpy.notCalled).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  49866123
haha
    ✓ should log 'haha'
    ✓ should do nothing


  2 passing (28ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/49866123

Comment: Thank you that is what I needed. I am using Jest and needed to mock substring so by doing as you suggested in jest like: jest.spyOn(String.prototype, 'substring').mockImplementation(() => 'Hello'); works!!