# Using sinon.spy to test global functions (such as parseInt) throwing error when running Karma

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon, karma-webpack

I'm having some trouble with spying on how often `parseInt` is run in my function. This is a PoC for my company's Typescript integration

I've followed two separate guides on testing Sinon, but none of them have mentioned working with functions from the `global` namespace.

Further, I haven't found any posts regarding the subject of using `spy` on global functions except [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866123/sinon-spy-on-tostring-method), which suggests it works..

Hovering over the `spy` function (`sinon.spy(global, "parseInt")`) also suggests that `parseInt` definitely is part of the global object / namespace in TypeScript

I'm getting this error which refers to a line that doesn't exist in the test-file:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'\nat scripts/fortress/typescript/tests/dependencies/func.spec.ts:119:0",
    "str": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'\nat scripts/fortress/typescript/tests/dependencies/func.spec.ts:119:0"
  }
```

**Removing all the lines but the one setting up the `spy` makes the test run fine.**

---

**The PoC test:**

```
    /**
     * @description Takes two parameters and determines if they are of the same type.
     * @param {string} property A Date string (example: 'Date(1231231311231)')
     * @returns {number} A number indicating the time from epoch.
     */
export class Functions { 
    getDateNumberFromJsonPropertyString(property : string) : number {
        return parseInt(property.substring(property.indexOf("(") + 1, property.indexOf(")")));
    }
}


    describe("GetdateNumberFromJsonPropertyString", function() {
        it("should call parseInt once", function() {
            let parseIntSpy = sinon.spy(global, "parseInt"); // <-- Breaks here

            func.getDateNumberFromJsonPropertyString("(1)");    

            parseIntSpy.restore(); 
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(parseIntSpy);
        }); 
    });
```

**Karma scafolding:**

```
/*
    KarmaJS defintion file for all required unit tests.
*/

let webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({ 
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],
        files: [
            "scripts/fortress/typescript/tests/**/*.ts"
        ], 
        exclude: [
            "node_modules/"
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            "scripts/fortress/typescript/tests/**/*.ts" : ["webpack"]
        },
        webpack: {
            mode: "development",
            module: webpackConfig.module,
            resolve: webpackConfig.resolve
        },
        reporters: ["progress"],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are restoring the spy before the assertion try:

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(parseIntSpy);
parseIntSpy.restore();
```