# Spying on a prototype method in Sinon.js

Tags: node.js, mocking, mocha.js, prototype, sinon

With sinon, I'm trying to spy on a prototype method. It looks so simple in online howtos etc. I tried many websites and SO posts like this: [Stubbing a class method with Sinon.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072016/stubbing-a-class-method-with-sinon-js) or [sinon - spy on toString method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866123/sinon-spy-on-tostring-method), but it just doesn't work for me.

**Prerequisites**

I'm using http.d.ts https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js to write data back from an async API call through an `OutgoingMessage` object:

`class OutgoingMessage extends stream.Writable`

There is a prototype method `end` in `OutgoingMessage`:

`OutgoingMessage.prototype.end = function end(chunk, encoding, callback) {`

My API function is called like this:

```
Get = async (req:IncomingMessage,res:OutgoingMessage):Promise<void> => {...
    ...
    res.end(data)
    ...
}
```

**My tests**

In my test I'm calling the `Get` method. My `IncomingMessage` determines what I expect to be in the `OutgoingMessage`.

```
it("should call end with the correct value", async function(){ 
    ...
    let outgoingMessageSpy = sinon.spy(OutgoingMessage.prototype,"end");
    let anOutgoingMessage = <OutgoingMessage>{};
    ...
    expect(outgoingMessageSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true();
}
```

Debugging the test case I see how `end` is being called but apparently I have not set up my spy the right way as my expectation fails, `calledOnce` is `false`. Inspecting the object I see that `calledCount` is `0`.

I'm doing basically the same (it appears to me) when I do

```
const toStringSpy = sinon.spy(Number.prototype, "toString");
expect(toStringSpy.calledWith(2)).to.be.true;
```

and that works. I do notice, though, that VS Code highlights the keyword `prototype` differently for `Number.prototype` and `OutgoingMessage.prototype`. Is that of relevance? On mouse-over is says `NumberConstructor.prototype` but only `OutgoingMessage.prototype`..

**Questions**

How to set up the spy correctly to pick up the call to the prototype method `end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up the spy correctly. **BUT**, there are conditions which can make the spy fail. For example: I saw you use async function, maybe you are not awaiting correctly on your async function test. Example below to show you that condition.

I have a very simple http server which has response with delay.

I create your Get method like this:

```
// File: get.ts
import { IncomingMessage, OutgoingMessage } from 'http';
import delay from 'delay';

const Get = async (req: IncomingMessage, res: OutgoingMessage): Promise<void> => {
  console.log('Get start');
  // I add this to show you that this async function need to be awaited.
  await delay(200);
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    data: 'Hello World!'
  }));
  console.log('Get finish');
};

export default Get;
```

And I create the main index.ts file.

```
// File: index.ts
import http, { IncomingMessage, OutgoingMessage } from 'http';
import Get from './get';

const server = http.createServer((req: IncomingMessage, res: OutgoingMessage) => {
  console.log('Receiving IncomingMessage');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  Get(req, res);
});

const port = 8000;
server.listen(port);
server.on('listening', () => {
  console.log(`Listen http on ${port}`);
});
```

I create the test file: get.spec.ts

```
// File: get.spec.ts
import sinon from 'sinon';
import http, { OutgoingMessage } from 'http';
import { Socket } from 'net';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import Get from './get';

describe('GET', () => {
  it('should call end with the correct value', async () => {
    // I copy paste from your code with minor code style edit.
    const outgoingMessageSpy = sinon.spy(OutgoingMessage.prototype, 'end');
    const socket = new Socket();
    const incoming = new http.IncomingMessage(socket);
    const outgoing = new http.OutgoingMessage();
    // This is just some private property which need to be set.
    (outgoing as any)._header = true;
    // NOTE: If you want invalid response, remove the "await".
    await Get(incoming, outgoing);

    // Set the debug message here before expect.
    console.log('SPY Counter:', outgoingMessageSpy.callCount);
    console.log('SPY CalledOnce:', outgoingMessageSpy.calledOnce);
    expect(outgoingMessageSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

When I run using ts-mocha from terminal, the result is like this:

```
$ npx ts-mocha get.spec.ts


  GET
Get start
Get finish
SPY Counter: 1
SPY CalledOnce: true
    ✓ should call end with the correct value (204ms)


  1 passing (206ms)
```

You see that you have setup the spy to OutgoingMessage.prototype.end correctly.

**BUT**, when you remove await inside the test (see NOTE inside get.spec.ts file), this is the result:

```
$ npx ts-mocha get.spec.ts


  GET
Get start
SPY Counter: 0
SPY CalledOnce: false
    1) should call end with the correct value


  0 passing (8ms)
  1 failing

  1) GET
       should call end with the correct value:

      AssertionError: expected false to be true
      + expected - actual

      -false
      +true

Get finish
```

The condition is: end method get called correctly but after the it test has been evaluated.